# Navigation Block in Header but Coded in Footer

Tags: css, navigation

Hello im really struggling to deal with my navigation area. The theme designer has put it in the footer but it displays at the top and its causing my young css mind to mental breakdown. I only ever ask advice when things have really got on top of me.

You can view the page here-
[my website](http://onlinebanter.com)

The #navigation is in yellow top left.

```
      <?php if (!empty($primary_links) || !empty($secondary_links)): ?>
      <div id="navigation" class="menu <?php if (!empty($primary_links)) { print "with-main-menu"; } if (!empty($secondary_links)) { print " with-sub-menu"; } ?>">
        <?php if (!empty($primary_links)){ print theme('links', $primary_links, array('id' => 'primary', 'class' => 'links main-menu')); } ?>
        <?php if (!empty($secondary_links)){ print theme('links', $secondary_links, array('id' => 'secondary', 'class' => 'links sub-menu')); } ?>
      <span class="test">efeeffefefefe</span></div> <!-- /navigation -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

with.....

```
     #navigation {
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 yellow;
float: left;
height: 65px;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: -100%;
padding: 0;
width: 75%;
```

}

```
.with-navigation #content,
.with-navigation .sidebar {
  margin-top: 65px;
```

}

that came with the theme. The original code for the navigation was...actually if you need to know that ill post it. I added that green box #test in a span which you can see in the code`. arrrghhhhh i give up. sorry. I actually want the green box on the left of the yellow navigation but it throws all the sidebars out. I will just leave it as it is for now but the original css code is-

```
     #navigation {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: -100%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
```

}

```
.with-navigation #content,
.with-navigation .sidebar {
  margin-top: 40px;
```

}

Ive tried everything. 14hrs yesterday and now 2 today. Could anyone show me how i can add a simple logo to the left of this navigation bar? Im at my wits end. Thanks

Comment: sorry thet #test css i am using is this - .test {
     background: none repeat scroll 0 0 green;
    float: right;
    height: 65px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 59px;
    top: 23px;
    width: 24%;
}

Comment: the #test is the div/span that i want to add my logo to. thanks

Answer (score 1):

For `.test`, **REMOVE:**

```
right: 59px;
top: 23px;
```

**CHANGE:**

```
float:right;
```

to

```
float:left;
```

For `#navigation` **REMOVE:**

```
margin-right:-100%;
```

**CHANGE:**

```
float:left;
```

to

```
float:right;
```

This will leave a little overlay which you can fix with the widths of the two elements according to your needs..

Comment: a brilliant thanks for your reply and time Omega. I did the changes as you mention and its half worked. If i change the width the green box should fit in there but as feared it's made the right hand blocks slip. You can view it here in one of my forums http://onlinebanter.com/chat

Comment: the sidebar in question is the #sidebar-second. Im tearing my hair out here. Only taken me 5 years to make a website thats still not open :(

Comment: 5 years? The ordering of your divs is causing this problem I believe. You should have the divs for the sidebars first, and then the div for the content. You can then float each side bar left and there shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: Thats the original problem i believe Omega. The theme has a 'negative margin trick' to output the navigation after the other divs but to display it first. There is more on it here but ive struggled with it http://drupal.org/node/480538 I'll go try and rip out the divs....no i wont as i dont know what im doing and spend the next 12hrs just trying to sort what i have done. Im gonna reset all the css and html and concentrate o the other aspects of my site i think. I'll have to come back to this as its starting to take over my life :(

Comment: ill just try and have the logo floated to the left of the header region. That might be easier.

Comment: I tried revisiting but couldn't find .test element any more. If you want a sidebar on each side then that is relatively easy considering the current ordering. Just remove the minus margin on the first side bar.